# Change CSS for one ID using this.id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, this

I have to `div` like this:

```
<div class="vignettes" id="vignette1"></div>
<div class="vignettes" id="vignette2"></div>
```

I want to do the same thing on Hover event for both `div`, let's say change the `background` to black:

```
$('.vignettes').hover(function () 
{
    //$('.vignettes').css("background", "#000");
    $(this.id).css("background", "#000");
}, 
function() 
{  
});
```

The commented line works, but obviously change both `div` to black when I hover one of them. I want to change only the hovered one. Instead of cloning my hover function with good `id`s, I want to get the `id` of the hovered one and change its `background` dynamically.

The code `alert(this.id)` pops up the good id, so `this.id` works.

But `$(this.id).css("background", "#000#");` doesn't do anything.

[JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/cLws40vr/3/)

Comment: What is #000# gonna do?

Comment: Even if it was a silly mistake, no need to downvote. @AmitJoki if you post it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ArthurRey undoed the downvote but you should have known it.

Comment: @Amit Joki: It is a bit silly to use a selector to find the *current element* by its own id :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie *that is exactly why I deleted my comment*. BTW I knew you were indicating my comment :)

Comment: I made my sample easier by selecting the current element, but the thing I want to do is select the `img` right after my hovered `div`. Hence the `$('#' + this.id + ' img')` is my solution. Just forgot the `'#'` before `this.id`

Comment: @Arthur Rey: Always show the *real* problem. That way assumptions are not made that simplify the answer too much :) For instance I would recommend using `data-` attributes in that scenario (not IDs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `this` *is* the target, just use `$(this).css("background", "#000");`

e.g.

```
$('.vignettes').hover(function () 
{
    $(this).css("background", "#000");
}, 
function() 
{  
});
```

*It is a bit silly to use a selector to find the current element by its own id as suggested*

In fact, most of the time, you do not even need IDs to do this sort of operation, just use classes to change the styling:

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cLws40vr/8/

```
$('.vignettes').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    console.log("test");
},

function () {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `$(this)`

When you are in a function like this, using `$(this)` will apply to the current element the event applies to.

```
$('.vignettes').hover(function () 
{
   $(this).css("background", "#000");
}, 
function() 
{  

});
```

Updated JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cLws40vr/4/

Answer (score 1):

As most of the other answers have suggested using this as the selector is the correct way to accomplish what you are trying to do in this case.

```js
$(this).css("background", "#000");
```

There is another error in your code that was causing your original code not to work.  To select using an id you need to add the hash symbol to the beginning of the selector string.

```js
$('#' + this.id).css("background", "#000");
```

I just thought I would point that out in case anyone was wondering why the original code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css("background", "#000");
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cLws40vr/5/